# Conditional probability calculation (multivariate distribution)

Tags: probability

X and Y are two i.i.d. random variables having the uniform distribution in $[0,1]$
The question is to calculate $Pr(Y\geq \frac{1}{2} | Y\geq 1-2X)$
My calculations: 
$$
\begin{align} 
Pr(Y\geq \frac{1}{2} | Y\geq 1-2X) &= \frac{Pr(Y\geq\frac{1}{2} \cap Y\geq 1-2X)}{Pr( Y\geq 1-2X)}\\
Pr(Y\geq\frac{1}{2} \cap Y\geq 1-2X) &= \int_{0}^{1/4}dx\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1-2x}dy\\
&= \frac{1}{16}\\
Pr(Y\geq 1-2X) &= \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{4}\\
\end{align}
$$
Making the total probability $\frac{1}{6}$. 
And once again I am incorrect, the answer is $\frac{7}{12}$. I really don't see how this answer can be found?

Comment: There seems to be a typo, in your first equation shouldn't you be dividing by $P(Y \geq 1 - 2X)$?

Comment: Yes, I fixed it.

Comment: Also the last probability seems to be wrong. Note that $X$ will have to run from $0$ to $1/2$ for $Y$ to satisfy its own limits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate this geometrically, at least as a check.

Let $A$ be the square with vertices $(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)$.

Let $R$ be the region inside $A$ with all points above $y=1-2x$ and above $y=1/2$.

Let $S$ be the region inside $A$ with all points above $y=1-2x$.

You can calculate the areas of these regions without calculus.

Then the probability you seek is Area(R)/Area(S).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The main problem seems to be in your first integral. You are essentially assuming $Y \geq 1/2$ and $Y$ is LESS THAN $1 - 2X$, based on the limits of integration, rather than having $Y \geq 1 - 2X$. Try integrating with respect to $X$ first by writing $1 \geq X \geq (1 - Y)/2$, and then integrating $Y$ from limits $1/2$ to $1$

Comment: I found my error. I was indeed integrating over the wrong area. Thanks for pointing it out :)